# Running into gems error on Rails 4

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm relatively new to Rails, and I'm trying to create a basic spree app using Rails 4.0. I recently tried to install an extension (spree_fancy) for my store, and while running the `bundle exec rails g spree_fancy:install` command, I keep seeing this message:

```
Unsupported rails environment for compass.
```

Before installing the extension, I could see my app load on local, but now I'm met with:

```
NoMethodError
```

and:

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm assuming this error is caused by spree_fancy. Is there a way to fix this? If not, how would I go about removing the spree_fancy gem? I removed it from the Gemfile, ran `gem uninstall spree_fancy`, and reinstalled my bundle, but this did not seem to do the trick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current released version of Spree does not support rails 4.  There is a branch of Spree which supports Rails 4 which you can read more about at this [Spree Rails 4 Blog Post](http://spreecommerce.com/blog/working-to-support-rails-4).

I don't believe that spree_fancy currently supports Rails 4, as it relies on Compass which does not support Rails 4.  There are a couple of branches which support rails 4, but spree_fancy isn't configured to use them.

Short version: Spree on Rails 4 isn't ready for prime time quite yet.  If you're new to rails, you should stick to 3.2.x for Spree.  Spree on Rails 4 will be ready in a few months, and you can upgrade then.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `Unsupported rails environment for compass.` error, this sounds like an issue with compass and Rails 4.

Use a version of `compass-rails` that's compatible with Rails 4 by changing the `gem 'compass-rails'` line in your `Gemfile` to:

```
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'milgner/compass-rails', branch: 'rails4'
```

I'm not sure if spree_fancy, itself, is compatible with Rails 4, so you might want to check out [Ready for Rails 4?](http://ready4rails4.net/) to see if gems that you're using are compatible with Rails 4.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great website! Unfortunately, spree_fancy isn't ready for Rails 4 yet